# Edit/Create access in Dynamics CRM for non licensed users

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, powerapps

We have a scenario where we do not have enough licenses to provide to the users for Dynamics CRM Online. But we need these users to be able to edit/create rows in Appointments and Task tables. We have a license with Admin access. Can this license be shared or used in such a way that users can edit these tables through any other interface say using Power Apps or so? Is there any way to enable them to edit the tables?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, get the per-user-per-app license for users so they can use Canvas app and get authenticated using AD SSO.

You can use the Admin service account to do data interactions into Dynamics CRM using MS Flow/Power Automate. Essentially CDS connector will use the licensed CRM admin account in the backend. Honestly I never tried this.

Another user also used HTTP request to use LogicApps to POST the data without license. [Reference](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Connection-to-Dynamics-365-using-a-Service-Account/td-p/64912)

PowerApps portals is another option.

Comment: Thanks Arun for your response. 
I am very new to all these apps/methods which you have mentioned. Even to use these apps don't the users require licenses to the apps? Sorry, if it's a very silly question. I absolutely have 0 experience working with these. Company wont spend any more for licenses. That's why I asked so. 
Is it possible to create webservices in CRM and create an external application to consume the webservices to read/insert records? What sort of licenses will that require for the users? Thanks again!

Comment: @user14413551 you have 10$/per user/per app/per month plan as I said. Or you can develop a website on your own to use CRM REST web api for data interactions. https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/

Comment: So when if i create a website to use CRM REST web api, will the users with no dynamics license be able to create records in dynamics crm? Will check with them too if they can provide power apps license with the plan you mentioned.

Comment: @user14413551 yeah, AzureAD app registration and App user in crm without license is enough for custom app/website route. https://powermaverick.dev/2019/03/10/azure-ad-authentication-with-dynamics-crm/

Comment: @user14413551 read my answer again, you may need Flow too for impersonating single service account for read/write crm data. You may need to contact MS sales for more cost effective plans. If this answer helped you, pls accept/upvote and close this thread.